# Some questions about SharePoint

Tags: designer-workflow

- Can a user create their own web page with customization?
- Can a user add free apps?
- Can the calendar be set up to show a different color for different events?
- Can a users reply to a discussion or poll be anonymous when wanted?

Comment: Welcome to sp.se. These are all separate questions and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

- To create and edit a web page, the user needs Designer permissions to the whole site.
- An administrator has to add apps
- Calendars can either use overlays to compile multiple calendars together with a separate color for each, or XSLT or javascript can be used to format item colors.
- A user can only reply anonymously if the library/list is set up to be anonymous by someone with Manage List or Full Control permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a user can create a own web page, as long as he has contribute permission at site level. More info

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Let-users-create-their-own-team-site-0e32bfa2-b771-4807-9d1e-f23bea3d95cf